# How to compile executable for Windows with GCC with Linux Subsystem?

Tags: c, bash, gcc

Windows 10 Anniversary Update includes the Linux Subsystem for Ubuntu. I installed gcc with `sudo apt-get install gcc`.

I wrote some simple C code for testing purposes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    printf("Hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And compiled it with `gcc -c main.c` but the execute (Linux only) `main.o` is generated. If I run it `./main.o`, it displays `Hello`.

My question is, how can I compile `main.c` so that Windows can run it? Basically, how do you generate a `*.exe` file with GCC in Linux Subsystem ?

Comment: `compile Windows exe`...aren't they already executable?

Comment: Your question is (to me at least) a bit unclear.  Can you provide more information outlining why what you get is different from what you expected.  Note also that by passing the `-c` option to the compiler you are explicitly telling it to perform the compilation step only -- and to *not* produce an executable by linking.

Comment: @G.M. If I want to get the `* .exe` file should I just make so `gcc -o main.exe main.c` ? The fact is that when I do it and try to ran this output file `main.exe` I got this http://i.imgur.com/NUDCslM.jpg

Comment: Did you try to run it inside or outside of Linux Subsystem?

Comment: @MarkusLaire I try to run it with double click on file

Comment: So. If even more specifically. I am wondering how to compile with gcc under a specific platform

Comment: Try to run it from command-line inside linux subsystem with `./main.exe`. If that works, then it seems that you might have linux executable, not windows.

Comment: @MarkusLaire yes, it's work in linux subsystem. but how can I compile specifically for the windows platform?

Comment: Since this seems to be fully linux system, you would need a cross-compiler to compile windows executable in linux.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120220/discussion-between-markus-laire-and-mikhail).

Comment: Use a cross-platform compiler

Comment: Try `gcc -Wall -g main.c -o myprog` (this produces a Linux ELF executable)  then run `./myprog`

Comment: It seems to me that OP wants to use gcc in LSW as a kind of cross-compiler to output a Windows PE format executable rather than an ELF executable. That way you could run it from a Command Prompt and not just from LSW bash. It's an interesting question and should be doable.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Linux Subsystem works as a Linux-computer. You can only run Linux executables inside it and default `gcc` creates Linux executables.

To create Windows executables, you need to install mingw cross-compiler:

```
sudo apt-get install mingw-w64
```

Then you can create 32-bit Windows executable with:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -o main32.exe main.c
```

And 64-bit Windows executable with:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o main64.exe main.c
```

Note that these Windows executables will not work inside Linux Subsystem, only outside of it.

Comment: The man page for gcc seems to imply that there are some options for making Windows console and windowed exes.  Is there any reason why they wouldn't work?

-mconsole
-mwindows

Comment: I don't have much experience with creating Windows apps, so I don't know the details of those compiler options. Still those Windows-specific options will only work with *-mingw32-gcc compilers and not default gcc which is creating Linux executables.

Comment: It seems like x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc is changed such that it is designed to use the windows C runtime (MSVCRT.DLL) and other core Windows libraries instead of the standard C libs gcc links (presumably whatever is in /lib?).

Comment: it seems to work but how can compile the file to .exe if the .c needs a .txt file as parameter

Comment: I doubt this is exactly correct. It says you "need to" use mingw. Surely that's only one option. GCC is famously supposed to be able to cross-compile between anything so surely it can also cross-compile x86-PE on an x86-ELF system? I don't know how to do it but it seems shocking if it's impossible.

Comment: Would there be any advantage to using mingw over cygwin? I was trying to avoid either.

Comment: Thanks, it's working. Sadly there are no documentation for mingw-w64.
@MarkusLaire is there any man pages for mingw-w64? I couldn't find any.

Comment: @YGautomo I've used mingw only for simple things and for me gcc docs have been enough: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/

Answer (score 11):

If you compile using gcc on linux it will produce an ELF file not a PE (what windows understand) file

To compile a program for windows inside linux you can use mingw.

Comment: How to use mingw to compile cpp file to exe