# Install OpenMpi on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mpi, openmpi

I am a computer science student and this season we have a course in MPI programming in C language. I don't have enough hard disk space to install visual studio on my computer and I have installed codeblocks, and MinGW as compiler, and I also installed [Microsoft MPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb524831(v=vs.85).aspx) to run mpi `.exe` code. Now I think that I need to install [Open mpi](https://www.open-mpi.org/) to compile my code to exe and run it using MSMPI. Please correct me if I'm wrong until now :)

In [OpenMPI download page](https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v3.0/) we just have binary codes, and I don't know how to install binary code in windows...

Thanks all

Comment: I don't know if this will work for your circumstance, but to compile C code on Windows, I enabled the [Linux Subsystem for Ubuntu](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/) which is available on Windows 10, then I installed [gcc](https://www.developerinsider.in/compile-c-program-with-gcc-compiler-on-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-10/) with `sudo apt-get install gcc` which allows for compiling code via the Linux Subsystem. This let me avoid having to deal with things like CodeBlocks and MinGW entirely.

Comment: If you use the Linux Subsystem for Ubuntu on Windows 10, then [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786014/how-to-compile-executable-for-windows-with-gcc-with-linux-subsystem) shows how to compile C code as `.exe` files for windows, which may work for what you desire, though I am not completely sure if it will work for all the `mpi` programming you want to do.

Comment: @DavyM I already have gcc and I can run regular `c` programs by it, but I need mpicc to compile a mpi code...

Comment: Since you are learning the C language, I recommend staying away from C++.  They are two distinct languages.  For example, C++ has `std::string` which can dynamically grow.  The C language uses fixed length character arrays, which must be compared using `strcmp`.  Please adjust your tags.

Answer (score 4):

If you plan to build your code with `Open MPI` and then run it with `Microsoft MPI`, then just drop that idea !
MPI is standard in a sense that a code can be **built** with any MPI implementation. There is no guarantee a binary can be **ran** with any MPI implementation.

`Open MPI` is not supported under windows, but you can use cygwin and install the openmpi packages. Linux subsystem for Ubuntu is an option i never tried but that might work too.

Comment: Interestingly, there are efforts being made on this front, especially in implementations of the same family! Of course MSMPI isn't part of it, but I wonder where we'll be in 10 years. https://www.mpich.org/abi/

Comment: Open MPI does not break ABI compatibility within the same major version.
https://github.com/cea-hpc/wi4mpi can be used if you want/need to mix Open MPI and MPICH

Comment: How do you install Open MPI with Cygwin?

Comment: Select it from the list of packages