# How can I run a C++ program on windows that was compiled in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I just compiled a simple "Hello World!" program on Linux. For reference, here it is:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

This program runs perfectly on Linux. The same code compiled on Windows can be run on Windows as well,  but I can't seem to compile it on Linux with `g++ myprog.cpp -o prog.exe` and *then* run it on Windows.

Shouldn't the machine code should be the same on Linux and Windows, because the program is the same?

Comment: The two platforms use different formats for their executables.

Comment: The machine code is not the same because the two use different [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).  Also, the executable file formats are completely different (ELF vs PE).

Comment: I/O is possibly the most platform-specific part of the standard library.

Comment: Have you looked at the compiled code and compared them? It's very unlikely that they are exactly the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786014/how-to-compile-executable-for-windows-with-gcc-with-linux-subsystem